# rails: Optimising multiple map calls on ar relation to single sql query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following relations:

```
class Bookmark
  belongs_to :collection
end

class Collection
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  has_many :collections
end
```

I am trying to get a list of foreign table records using the below map calls

```
Bookmark.where(id: [...]).map(&:collection).map(&:user)
```

this works, but was just wondering if there is any way I can optimise this to a single sql query?
I have done this before using joins for has_many associations, but am unsure how to apply this for single child associations like above.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be the same as

```
User.joins(:collections).where(collections: { bookmark_id: [...] })
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `joins` will make it single query but when you start rendering the data or read the result it will fire individual queries on associated tables leading to **N + 1** queries problem. Would recommend using `includes` or `preload` instead of `joins` to avoid this problem.